# How to fix error in foreach loop, my data in for each is not inserting?

Tags: php, html, mysql, bootstrap-5, dynamicform

I'm using dynamic form and I want to insert data, my form is inserting data in two different tables ,the problem is inserting data in the second table is not working, the data is coming from the dynamic form and using foreach loop.
heres the error. (I used the echo to find the error)

```
INSERT INTO `tbl_family_profiling`(`family_number`, `date_of_interview`,`interviewer`, `interviewee`, `barangay`, `residence`, `length_of_residency`, `address`, `primarycare_provider`, `primarycare_provider_no`, `travel_time`, `mode_of_transportation`) VALUES ('020001911','2022-11-10','dwqdqd','Anna Biat',' sandiego', 'Male','','',' ',' ','',' ')
```

> Warning: foreach() argument must be of type array|object, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\HMO_Home\insert_familyprofiling.php on line 34

heres is my code

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){


$fserial = $_POST['familyserial'];   
$doi = $_POST['date_of_interview'];
$intvwer = $_POST['interviewer'];
$intvwee = $_POST['interviewee'];
$barangay = $_POST['barangay'];
$residence = $_POST['residence'];
$lghtresidence = $_POST['residencylenght'];
$address = $_POST['address'];
$pcareprovider = $_POST['primarycareprovider'];
$pcareno = $_POST['primarycareno'];
$ttime = $_POST['traveltime'];
$mode_transportation = $_POST['mode_of_transportation'];

echo $sql = "INSERT INTO `tbl_family_profiling`(`family_number`, ` 
date_of_interview`,`interviewer`, `interviewee`,barangay`, `residence`, `length_of_residency`, `   address`, `primarycare_provider`, primarycare_provider_no`, `travel_time`,
mode_of_transportation`) VALUES ('$fserial','$doi','$intvwer','$intvwee',' $barangay',
'$residence','$lghtresidence','$address',' $pcareprovider',' $pcareno','$ttime',' 
$mode_transportation')";

// $query = $con->query($sql) or die ($con->error);


$student_id = $con->insert_id;

foreach ($_POST['familymember'] as $key => $value) {

echo  $query1 = "INSERT INTO 
twofamilyprofiling_family_members(user_id,family_member,family_position,
    sex,birthday,marital_status,blood_type,disability,highest_education_attainment,occupation,
    contact_no, religion, nhip)VALUES 
    ('" . $student_id . "','" . $_POST['familymember'][$key] . "',
    '" . $_POST['familyposition'][$key] . "','" . $_POST['sex'][$key] . "','" . 
    $_POST['birthday'][$key] . "',
    '" . $_POST['maritalstatus'][$key] . "','" . $_POST['bloodtype'][$key] . "','" . 
    $_POST['disability'][$key] . "',
    '" . $_POST['educationalattainment'][$key] . "','" . $_POST['occupation'][$key] . "','" . 
    $_POST['contactno'][$key] . "',
    '" . $_POST['religion'][$key] . "','" . $_POST['nhip'][$key] . "')";

    // $query = $con->query($query1) or die ($con->error);
}
```

}

```
<h4 class="ITRtitle justify-content-center text-center shadow">I. Assesment of the Family, Home and Environmental Conditions</h4>
                    
                    <div id="dynamic_field">
                    <div class="FProfile row">
                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                        <label for="inputfamilymember" class="form-label">Family Member</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control mt-4" name="familymember[]" id="inputfamilymember">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-2"  style="width: 10rem; margin-left: -20px;">
                      <label for="inputfamilyposition" class="form-label ">Family Position</label>
                      <input type="text"  style="width: 5rem;" class="form-control mt-4"  name="familyposition[]" id="inputfamilyposition">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-2"  style="width: 5rem; margin-left: -50px;">
                        <label for="inputsex" class="form-label">Sex</label>
                        <select id="inputsex" name="sex[]" class="form-select mt-4"  style="width: 4rem;">
                          <option>F</option>
                          <option>M</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-2" style="width: 10rem; margin-left: -15px;">
                        <label for="inputbirthday" class="form-label">Birthday</label>
                        <input type="date" class="form-control mt-4" name="birthday[]" id="inputbirthday">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-2" style="width: 6rem; margin-left: -20px;">
                        <label for="inputmaritalstatus" class="form-label">Marital status</label>
                        <select id="inputmaritalstatus" name="maritalstatus[]" class="form-select">
                          <option>S</option>
                          <option>W</option>
                          <option>Sep</option>
                          <option>CL</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-2" style="width: 5.5rem; margin-left: -22.5px;">
                        <label for="inputBloodType" class="form-label">Blood Type</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="bloodtype[]" id="inputBloodType">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-2" style="width: 8rem; margin-left: -22.5px;">
                        <label for="inputdisability" class="form-label">Disability</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control mt-4" name="disability[]" id="inputdisability">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-2" style="width: 8rem; margin-left: -22.5px;">
                        <label for="inputEducationAttainment" class="form-label">Educational Attainment</label>
                        <select id="inputEducationAttainment" name="educationalattainment[]" class="form-select">
                          <option>No Formal Education</option>
                          <option>Elementary</option>
                          <option>HighSchool</option>
                          <option>Vocational</option>
                          <option>College</option>
                          <option>Post Graduate</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-2" style="width: 7rem; margin-left: -22.5px;">
                        <label for="inputoccupation" class="form-label">Occupation</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control mt-4" name="occupation[]" id="inputoccupation">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-2" style="width: 9rem; margin-left: -22.5px;">
                        <label for="inputcontactno" class="form-label">Contact No.</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control mt-4" name="contactno[]" id="inputcontactno">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-2" style="width: 6rem; margin-left: -22.5px; fontweight: 0.5px;">
                        <label for="inputreligion" class="form-label">Religion</label>
                        <select id="inputreligion" name="religion[]" class="form-select mt-4">
                          <option>Roman Catholic</option>
                          <option>Iglesia</option>
                          <option>Born Again</option>
                          <option>Muslim</option>
                          <option>Seven Adventist</option>
                          <option>Others</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-2" style="width: 7rem; margin-left: -22.5px;">
                        <label for="inputNHIP" class="form-label">NHIP</label>
                        <select id="inputNHIP" name="nhip[]" class="form-select mt-4">
                          <option>write direct</option>
                          <option>indirect</option>
                          <option>dependent</option>
                          <option>non-member</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col" style="width: 7rem; margin-left: -22.5px;">
                                    <td><button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-success"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button></td>
                                </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: Are you sure that you are passing an array to your foreach?

Comment: @LucasdeRijke yes? i think so

Comment: FYI: If this HTML is supposed to be present in the document multiple times, then you labels won't work properly, because your input field IDs are not unique.

Comment: And `td` elements outside of `tr` also make no sense.

Comment: @CBroe I'm not using the ids of my input fields I only use the name of the field to reference my data

Comment: put ```var_dump($_POST['familymember']);``` somewere before your foreach too check if its an array or just a string.

Comment: But you _are_ using the IDs of your input fields in the `for` attribute of your `label` elements.

Comment: Why have `id`s if you don't use them? Either way, having duplicate `id`s is invalid.

Comment: @CBroe I'm not sure but anyway thank you very much

Comment: @brombeer noted

Comment: I've already fix it, @LucasdeRijke is right the problem is the data I;m passing which is not array

Comment: Thhanks everyone